# Как копировать элементы массива подходящие по критерию в другой массив Java

Tags: java, массивы

Не могу пустой массив заполнить числами проходящими через if из другого массива.

Дана задача:
Дан одномерный массив Zm. Сформировать массив Yn, состоящий из элементов массива Zm, значение которых меньше среднего арифметического нечетных элементов исходного массива.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] Zm={6, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1};
    int Yn[];
    System.out.println("Задание 5.1. : "+zad1(Xn));
    zad2(Zm,Yn);
}

public static int zad1(int[] a){
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i]>=0)
            j++;
    return j;
}

public static void zad2(int[] a,int c[]){
    int b=0,j=0,arg,g=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if(a[i]%2!=0) {
            b = b + a[i];
            j++;
        }
    arg = b / j;
    System.out.print("Задание 5.2. : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if((a[i]%2!=0)&&(a[i]<arg)) {
            c[g]=a[i];
            if ((i+1)!=a.length)
            System.out.print(c[g]+", ");
            else System.out.println(c[g]);
            g++;
        }
    }

}}
```

Comment: Ругается на то что Yn не инициализирован

Comment: Ну так инициализируйте его

Comment: Yn - объявлен, но не инициализирован.....надо бы ему, для приличия, длину хоть задать ? `int Yn[] = new int[Zm.length];` ?

Comment: А можно чтобы длина массива была равна числу элементов которые я хочу в него положить?

Comment: ну да. вместо `Zm.length` пишите нужное число.... но с массивами это тяжко, т.к. нужно выяснить это конкретное число.... проще arraylist'ом обходится......... либо создать массив хотя бы на 1 элемент изначально, но при очередной итерации по условию, что элемент должен быть положен в массив, а места уже нет - делать доп. манипуляции по расширению исходного, что накладывают свой отпечаток.......еще один вариант: нужные элементы конкатинировать в строку через запятую. А в конце эту строку разбить на массив, через `split()`, тогда не придется знать заранее длину массива

Comment: динамический массив поможет. он не имеет определенного размера. расширяется по мере необходимости. `int *Yn = new int;`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых: в строке `System.out.println("Задание 5.1. : "+zad1(Yn));` 
передается непонятно какая переменная "Yn", которую вы не создали и ничего туда не занесли (если это был массив, то надо было обозначить размеры, а во-вторых занести туда цифры перед выводом).

Вот что я накалякал :)

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] Zm = { 6, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1 };
        // Обращаемся к методу который вернет "правильный" массив
        int[] Yn = filtr(Zm);
        // Выводим для самопроверки :)
        System.out.print("Получившийся результат : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < Yn.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + Yn[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] filtr(int mas1[]) {
        int Arithmetic = 0;
        int count = 0;
        // Считаем сумму нечетных цифр массива а так же сколько это цифр
        for (int i = 0; i < mas1.length; i++) {
            if (mas1[i] % 2 == 1) {
                Arithmetic = Arithmetic + mas1[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        // Считаем среднее арифметическое
        Arithmetic = Arithmetic / count;
        // Обнуляем счетчик
        count = 0;
        // Считаем сколько у нас получилось нечетных цифр выходящих за среднее
        // арифметическое или равное ему
        for (int i = 0; i < mas1.length; i++) {
            if (mas1[i] <= Arithmetic && mas1[i] % 2 == 1) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        // Инициализируем новый массив на ту сумму нечетных цифр
        int[] mas2 = new int[count];
        //Создаем еще один счетчик для нового массива
        int count2 = 0;
        //Переносим значения старого массива в новый
        for (int i = 0; i < mas1.length; i++) {
            if (mas1[i] <= Arithmetic && mas1[i] % 2 == 1) {
                mas2[count2] = mas1[i];
                count2++;
            }
        }
        //Возвращаем получившийся массив
        return mas2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да , достаточно поменять оба раза условие "mas1[i] >= Arithmetic"

Comment: Поменял :)
бе бе бе

Answer (score 0):

здесь есть неоднозначность в задании -- что есть "нечетный элемент"?

- это элемент с нечётным индексом в массиве (в java индексация идёт с 0, а ноль -- это чётное число)
- это элемент у которого порядковый номер нечётныё (нумерация идёт с 1)
- это элемент у которого значение является нечётным

сейчас считает для элементов с нечётным индексом

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] Zm = {6, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1};
        int[] Yn = filterArray(Zm);
        System.out.println("Result: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(Yn));
    }

    static int[] filterArray(int srcArray[]) {
        float averageOdds = averageOdds(srcArray);
        int dstSize = countElements(srcArray, averageOdds);
        int[] dstArray = new int[dstSize];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++) {
            if (srcArray[i] < averageOdds) {
                dstArray[j++] = srcArray[i];
            }
        }
        return dstArray;
    }

    /**
     * подсчитывает количество элементов значение которых меньше value 
     */
    static int countElements(int[] array, float value) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int item : array) {
            if (item < value) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * вычисляет среднее арифметическое элементов массива которые имеют нечётный индекс
     */
    static float averageOdds(int[] array) {
        // если кол-во элементов 0 или 1, то вычислять нечего
        if (array.length < 2) {
            return 0;
        }
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
        return sum / (array.length / 2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author DMyrzaka
 */
public class Massive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] Zm={6, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1};
    //int Yn[];
    System.out.println("Задание 5.1. : "+zad1(Zm));
    zad2(Zm);
}

    public static int zad1(int[] a){
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i]>=0)
            j++;
    return j;
}


public static void zad2(int[] a){
    int b=0,j=0,arg,g=0;
    int c[] = new int[a.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if(a[i]%2!=0) {
            b = b + a[i];
            j++;
        }
    arg = b / j;
    System.out.print("Задание 5.2. : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if((a[i]%2!=0)&&(a[i]<arg)) {
            c[g]=a[i];
            if ((i+1)!=a.length)
            System.out.print(c[g]+", ");
            else System.out.println(c[g]);
            g++;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Неплохо бы сопроводить код хоть каким-то текстом, раскрывающим его смысл.

Comment: @Nofate он все равно неправильный) В смысле тут нет решения на нужный вопрос, так скажем

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Зато лицензия есть :)